# How to rid smell from a closed Refrigerator

Tags: cleaning

I was given a refrigerator that has been in storage for almost a year. The door was not propped open and now has a smell.
What is the best way to get rid of the smell and will it be safe to use?

Comment: And [How to kill the stink in an unplugged refrigerator?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1789/how-to-kill-the-stink-in-an-unplugged-refrigerator)

Comment: I've had success with 1. Wipe the interior with a mix of 2 tablespoons baking soda and 1 quart hot water. Rinse with a damp cloth, then dry with a clean dry cloth Step 2 Put (unused!) unperfumed cat litter, the kind that is made from fuller's earth, often called 'clumping' litter on or more trays and leave in the fridge, running, with the door closed for 2-3 days. If this fails, you can try the same with activated charcoal which you can get from pet or drug stores. Or mix the two.